# background image not rendering on wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs

Topic explains it all. I've got it set as...

```
  body{
         background-image:url('images/bg.gif');
         background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-y;
      }
```

Can't seem to figure out why it's not rendering in the background. I'm new to wordpress themeing in general. Could anyone help me out? I've posted a link to the content in full below.

http://www.aidanchurch.com/blog/

Comment: Unrelated: Now that you have the background image working, I would lighten it up a bit. It makes me dizzy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the style sheet, I see some garbage characters right in front of the

`body{ background-image:url('images/bg.gif');`

line in the css file. Those might be making the rendering skip the rule. I'd backspace and clean that up.

Comment: Yep those characters are no good. Missing an opening curly brace as well. http://www.aidanchurch.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bloo_06/style.css

Comment: I looked at it and it says `ï»¿bo y` that is definitely not the `body` tag and likely why the rule is not being applied.

Comment: disregard my first comment. Thanks!

Comment: @songdogtech - thanks for the reminder that firebug does not always hold all of the answers.

Comment: Glad that worked. Interesting that Firebug didn't show the junk. And I didn't see the missing opening brace.

Comment: @songdogtech - Yeah, Firebug likes to clean things up - which explains why @Marcus couldn't see any rules being applied to the body. I think that brace went missing as @Aidanc was modifying.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you background image is located here:

> http://www.aidanchurch.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bloo_06/images/bg.gif

So first of all try an absolute address like so:

```
background-image: url('/blog/wp-content/themes/bloo_06/images/bg.gif');
```

However if that works, you really want a relative URL, so take a look at the directory structure of your theme and ensure the background image is indeed relative to the css file you have written that rule in, in the way you have written.

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I had tried that earlier and also tested with firebug and the URL images/bg.gif does render. I've also made a static content page without wordpress and it renders the background image too.

Comment: Well I am not seeing **any** CSS rules applied to you `body` tag at all.

Comment: Firebug only seems to show my CSS when you go to a different page the click the back arrow back to the blog.

Comment: haha, my firebug was freaking out too because of those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have uploaded the correct image to the correct place.  When I tried to view the image I could see a very small and transparant image.  http://www.aidanchurch.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bloo_06/images/bg.gif .